# How does $F_p$ genrated?

Tags: classical-mechanics

**Leaning pole**

A pole of negligible mass leans against a wall, at angle $θ$ with the
horizontal. Gravity is directed down.

(a) Find the constraint relating the vertical acceleration of one
end to the horizontal acceleration of the other.

(b) Now suppose that each end carries a pivoted mass $M.$ Find
the initial vertical and horizontal components of acceleration as the
pole just begins to slide on the friction less wall and floor. Assume
that at the beginning of the motion the forces exerted by the rod
are along the line of the rod. (As the motion progresses, the system
rotates and the rod exerts side wise forces.)

**Figure:**

[image]

Solution:

[image]

**Question 1(Q1)**
How does $F_p$ genrated?

**Question 2(Q2)**
From the figure, $M\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=F_p\cos\theta$ instead of $M\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=F_p\sin\theta$. Right?

Comment: The force $F_p$ characterizes the traction/compression force along the pole.

Comment: @Cesareo I don't understand. What object is applying $F_p$? when a pole lay on the wall I know there will be a Normal force due to the molecular interaction of wall on the pole. what about $F_p$?

Comment: Suppose you make a cut on the pole. One half is interacting with the other half with a force aligned along the pole, being a compression or traction force $\vec F_p$. Now consider the solid associated to the upper mass with the attached pole half. This solid with mass $M$ (the pole is massless) is actuated by the following forces: $M\vec g, \vec N_h$ and $\vec F_p$.

Comment: Means normal force acting on the upper mass by pole. right?

Comment: What about the equation 3?@Cesareo

Comment: Nope. The compound body (mass+half pole) is actuated by $\vec W, \vec F_p$ and $\vec N_h$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111963/discussion-between-unknown-x-and-cesareo).

Comment: It appears to me as being $M\ddot x = F_p\cos\theta$